# PostgreSQL: selecting rows that occur on a certain day of the week, in a specific time zone

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timezone

I've got a table that stores "snapshot" data - the number of staff at work is captured every 10 minutes and stored in it. I'd like to generate a report to show the number of staff at work over the course of a day on a specific weekday (eg. for the last four Sundays).

In Rails my query looks like this:

```
<model>.where("EXTRACT(dow FROM (time + interval '#{time_zone_offset} hours')) = ?", Time.zone.now.wday)
       .where('time BETWEEN ? AND ?', 5.weeks.ago.end_of_week, 1.week.ago.end_of_week)
       .select("organisation_id, date_trunc('hour', time) as grouped_time, avg(staff) as staff")
       .group("grouped_time").order("grouped_time")
```

And that translates to this SQL:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', time) as grouped_time, avg(staff) as staff
FROM <model>
WHERE (EXTRACT(dow FROM (time + interval '10 hours')) = 0)
AND (time BETWEEN '2013-09-22 13:59:59.999999' AND '2013-10-20 13:59:59.999999')
GROUP BY grouped_time
ORDER BY grouped_time
```

In this case, `time_zone_offset` would differ based on the user I am doing the lookup for:

```
def time_zone_offset
  @tzoffset ||= ActiveSupport::TimeZone[current_user.organisation.time_zone].utc_offset / 60 / 60
end
```

(The current time zone is also set in an around_filter, so that the `1.week.ago` etc. are in the correct zone.)

My database's time zone is UTC (`set TIME ZONE 'UTC'`).

This works, but I'm sure there's a better way to do find records on a particular day of the week then by manipulating the `interval` by hand. I also don't think that will work with DST in time zones where that is applicable. I know PostgreSQL is capable of [converting a `time with time zone` to a particular time zone](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT), but that doesn't include a date, so I can't figure out the day of the week! Other WHERE clauses I have tried:

- `EXTRACT (dow from time') = 0` - this gives me snapshots between 10 AM Sunday and 10 AM Monday
- `EXTRACT (dow from time at time zone 'Brisbane/Australia') = 0` - this gives me actions between 8pm Sunday and 8pm Monday. My understanding is that this happens because Postgres treats the `time` field as if it is in Brisbane time, instead of *converting* it from UTC to Brisbane time.

So I'd love to know if there is something I should be doing to get this query working.

Comment: what's the datatype of the `time` column? what's the SQL session's time zone (`show time zone`) when the rows are inserted? Is it also forced to `UTC`?

Comment: `time` is a `timestamp without time zone`. SQL session time zone is "UTC".

Comment: Always provide (the relevant part of) your table definition like `\d tbl` in psql gives you. And your Postgres version. Add some sample data, optionally in an SQLfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AT TIME ZONE` when applied to a `timestamp without timezone` produces a `timestamp with timezone` (and the other way around). And this `timestamp with timezone` is interpreted in your session's timezone (which in your case is forced to `UTC`).

So the expression `EXTRACT (dow from time at time zone 'Brisbane/Australia')` does not extract the day in Brisbane at *`time` (UTC)*, it extracts the day corresponding to the converted *`time`* from the point of view of someone virtually living in the UTC time zone.

As an example, when I'm typing this, if pretending to be in UTC:

```
=> set timezone to 'UTC';
=> select now(),now() at time zone 'Australia/Brisbane';
             now              |         timezone          
------------------------------+---------------------------
 2013-10-27 18:01:03.15286+00 | 2013-10-28 04:01:03.15286
```

Fine, it's Sunday 18:01 in UTC and Monday 04:01 at Brisbane

But if applying the timezone displacement to a `timestamp without timezone`:

```
select now(),now()::timestamp at time zone 'Australia/Brisbane';
              now              |           timezone            
-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 2013-10-27 18:01:57.878541+00 | 2013-10-27 08:01:57.878541+00
```

Notice how the second column differs from the previous result. It's actually 20 hours off of Brisbane expressed in UTC: it's presumably the technically correct answer to a question that doesn't make much sense.

Presumably you want this:

```
EXTRACT (dow from (time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') at time zone 'Brisbane/Australia')=0
```

which should answer: does the date and time *`time`* as measured in UTC corresponds to a Sunday in Brisbane?

Comment: Awesome, that seems to get the right results. Thanks for the explanation! I think I understand a bit better now :)